# Displaying asterisks vs. displaying characters with a function

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote a function (`asterisksDisplay`) that displays a solid rectangle of asterisks whose sides are specified in the integer parameters as `row` and `column`, which are taken from the user. The program below works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void asterisksDisplay (int row, int column);

int main (void)
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    printf("Please enter sides of your shape: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("\nYour shape is: \n");
    asterisksDisplay(a, b);
}

void asterisksDisplay (int row, int column)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        for (int p = 1; p <= column; p++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

When I try to modify this function of asterisks to a function of a user given character display, somehow compiler skips displaying the character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void asterisksDisplay (int row, int column, char character);
int main (void)
{
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    char c;
    printf("Please enter sides of your shape: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("\nplease enter the character to be filled: ");
    scanf("%s", &c);
    printf("\n");
    asterisksDisplay(a, b, c);
}

void asterisksDisplay (int row, int column, char character)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        for (int p = 1; p <= column; p++) {
            printf("%c", character);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

what is the solution for fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 scanf("%s", &c);
```

to

```
 scanf(" %c", &c);
          ^^-----------------------(i)
       ^^------------------------- (ii)
```

- Change of the conversion specifier from `%s` to `%c`, as (i): because `c` is a `char` type.
- We need to escape the previously entered newline, so the extra whitespace before the conversion specifier, which matches and discards any leading whitespace input present in the buffer.

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately, this is not the solution. Also, Xcode insists that I should change the %c to %s on scanf. I will try the code on visual studio and post the result.

Comment: I tried the code with Visual Studio. If I change the %s with %c as you suggested, It still skips the output. Program gets 2 integers as size of our shape, and displays "Please enter character" and exits the program. If I keep %s it gives an error: Not enough arguments passed for format string.